# she shows little appreciation of good music

Tags: sentence-meaning

What's actually meant by "She shows little appreciation of good music"?

Taking "appreciation" as "pleasure", does it mean "she doesn't really enjoy good music"?

Another definition as "understanding", can I say "she hasn't got any taste for good music"?

Comment: i would assume the latter. Teaching 'musical appreciation' means helping children to  enjoy (usually classical) music by learning to understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

It means that she shows ***almost no appreciation***.

Without the aticle "a" preceding it, ***little*** has a negative meaning:

> not as much as may be expected or wished for. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/little-a-little-few-a-few))

[Collins](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/quantifiers) describes the quantifier *little* as meaning:

> ‘not much’
>
> - The students were given very ***little** help* with their projects.
> - Edward got ***little** encouragement* from his parents.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I might have not been quite clear. The thing is, which of the definitions of "appreciation" above could be applied? The former "not really enjoying" or the latter "having a poor taste for good music"?